# If $[L:K]$ is prime, show that $L/K$ is a simple extension.

Tags: galois-theory

Let L/K be a field extension with [L:K] = p, where p is prime. Show that L/K is a simple extension.

I tried using the Tower Law but to no avail. I'd be grateful if somebody can assist me with a hint!

Comment: The "Tower Law" is $[M : K] = [M : L]\cdot [L : K]$?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Okay. But if you tried using that, I don't see how you didn't manage to show it. Can you explain a bit more of what you did? How did you try to use the Tower Law?

Comment: Let $x \in L\setminus K$, then $K(x)$ is not $K$ so what could it be?

Comment: I think I've got it: since L/K is a finite extension, every element a in L is algebraic over K, and a theorem tell us that [K(a):K] = p (since the minimum polynomial in K must have degree p), and this means that [L:K(a)] = 1 by the tower law. This is equivalent to saying that L=K(a). QED

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $L/K$ isn't simple. As a finite extension, $L$ is of the form $K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$, where $\alpha_i\not\in K$. Then $K(\alpha_1)$ is an intermediate field. Use the tower law now.

Comment: But isn't K(a1,...,an) = K(a1 + a2 + ... +an) anyway, and this RHS is simple?

Comment: @Richard Not necessarily. For example, you don't have $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}+(-\sqrt{2}))$.

Comment: So by the tower law, [K(a1, ... , an) : K(a1)] = 1, which means that L = K(a1) which is simple. Does this mean that every element in L \ K is a generator for L?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Great, thanks everyone, you've been very helpful as always!

Comment: Why does $\alpha_i  \not \in K$?

Comment: @Joey We can always pick $\alpha_i$ to be outside $K$ - if they were in $K$, they could be removed, since $K(a)=K$ for $a\in K$.